# How to check if any music is playing in XCode

Tags: sprite-kit

How can I check if any sound is playing in the background and if true, it stops? 
I tried this but didn't succeed:

```
        if audioPlayerMainMusic.isPlaying{
        audioPlayerMainMusic.stop()
    }
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: In the background of what? I assume you're doing work in let say... excel and you don't hear music playing and wonder... what happened? Elaborate a little in your question (self-edit is aloud) because now your setting is too broad.

Comment: Give us more context please. Also this question has nothing with Xcode IDE, but rather with a specific framework and Swift.